# upload pictures from gallery or take from camera in webview

Tags: android, android-webview, image-gallery

I am working on android app that shows a website only,the website have a button that clicking on it makes you upload a picture.the problem is the app doesn't respond when clicking on the button of the site.

Thanks  in advance

Here the main activity code

```
package com.eizeasta.dame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import com.eizeasta.dame.R;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView view;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    private WebView browser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.admob_id);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        progressBar= (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipelayout);
        final WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.refresh,R.color.refresh1,R.color.refresh2);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                browser.reload();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                    }
                },20000);
            }
        });
        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        //mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = browser.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        browser.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        browser.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        browser.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        browser.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        // Use remote resource
        browser.loadUrl("https://www.sameh.com/forum/_tbdl");

        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    try {
                        webView.stopLoading();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                    }

                    webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Check your internet connection and try again.");
                    alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                            startActivity(getIntent());
                        }
                    });

                    alertDialog.show();
                    super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
                }


            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {
                findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        } );

        // Use local resource
        //mWebView.loadUrl("file:android_asset/web/egypt-post.html");
    }

    // Prevent the back-button from closing the app
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(browser.canGoBack()) {
            browser.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and the **android manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.eizeasta.dame" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.eizeasta.dame.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: @SudheeshR  can you help please?

Comment: let me check your code

Comment: As far as I know this isn't built into the Android API directly. However, you can use PhoneGap, which provides Javascript hooks into native device functionality (i.e., the camera).

Comment: You can refer these links (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675372/how-to-launch-camera-from-button-in-webview-android) and  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803914/can-i-open-camera-in-webview)

Comment: Thanks for your care. I will check it and return back to you